# Неправильно работает обработчик маршрутов в Next JS 13.4

Tags: nextjs

Использую **Next js 13.4** и **api** у меня немного странно работает.

Смотрел туторы и везде использовали такой формат обращения за данными **"/api/название api"**.

В моём же случае, такой подход не работает и мне приходится прописывать полный путь к api.

Заранее говорю, что пост с решение подобной проблемы мне не помог: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247789/route-handlers-is-not-working-in-next-js-13-2-and-return-error

В чём может быть проблема?

[image: Структура проекта]

API GET метод

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { datas } from "./videos";

export async function GET(request:NextRequest){
    const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
    
    const query = searchParams.get("query");

    let currentDatas = datas;

    if(query && /^-?\d+$/.test(query)){
        currentDatas = datas.filter(data => data.post_id === Number(query));
    }

    return NextResponse.json(currentDatas);
}
```

Функции запроса

```
import { CardVideoPostIF } from "@/types/Interfaces";

const host = process.env.HOST as string;

export async function actionGetVideos(){
    const response = await fetch(`http://${host}/api/videos`, { next: { revalidate: 3600 } });
    if (!response.ok){throw new Error("Error 200 | videos posts api")}
    const datas: CardVideoPostIF[] = await response.json();
    return datas;
}

export async function actionGetByVideos(id:number){
    const response = await fetch(`/api/videos?query=${id}`, { next: { revalidate: 3600 } });
    if (!response.ok){throw new Error("Error 200 | videos posts api")}
    const datas: CardVideoPostIF[] = await response.json();
    return datas[0];
}
```

Ошибка

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Failed to parse URL from /api/videos?query=7

Call Stack
new Request
node:internal/deps/undici/undici (7134:19)
fetch1
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react\cjs\react.shared-subset.development.js (237:80)
doOriginalFetch
file:///C:/Users/robbi/Documents/GitHub/Leonardo/leonardo/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/patch-fetch.js (278:24)
<unknown>
file:///C:/Users/robbi/Documents/GitHub/Leonardo/leonardo/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/patch-fetch.js (415:20)
```

Comment: Почему не надо добавлять описания ошибок в виде скриншотов: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375